# Creating an MFC application manually in VS2017

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to compile an MFC application under VS2017.

I created this application from an empty C++ project.

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class CMyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CFrameWnd* pFrame = new CFrameWnd;
        if (!pFrame)
            return FALSE;

        pFrame->Create(NULL, _T("Minimal MFC Application"));
        m_pMainWnd = pFrame;
        pFrame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        pFrame->UpdateWindow();

        return TRUE;
    }
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    CMyApp app;
    AfxWinInit(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);
    return app.Run();
}
```

Then I added `nafxcwd.lib` and `libcmtd.lib` via the linkes.

Then I set

- `MyProjet` -> `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Code Generation` -> `Runtime Library` -> `Debug` = `/MDd`
- `MyProjet` -> `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Code Generation` -> `Runtime Library` -> `Release` = `/MD`

Now, I am getting the following error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>_WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1>nafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(delete_scalar.obj)
1>C:\Users\pc\source\repos\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "Project2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**How can I resolve this error?**

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask, why are you spending your time doing this? Create a basic project with the builtin wizards and then compare that against your efforts.

Comment: The linker is telling you. The symbol is defined in *libcmtd.lib* and *nafxcwd.lib*. If you don't want an LNK2005 error, don't link against both libraries.

Comment: FWIW, this compiles fine with VS 2022 (w/o extra libs, just adding a lib directory, without UNICODE defined). Doens't work though *"appcore.cpp(783) : AppMsg - Warning: m_pMainWnd is NULL in CWinApp::Run - quitting application." *

Comment: Have you tried Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, No. VS2022 don't run on my laptop.

Comment: Try removing nafxcwd.lib and libcmtd.lib.  Then add `_AFXDLL` in properties-> preprocessor.  Set subsystem: Windows. Will it work?